# Error while showing left view of tree

Tags: c++, debugging, data-structures

I have initialize tree by myself as the following :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data = 0;
    node* left = nullptr;
    node* right = nullptr;
};
void construct(struct node* &tree)
{
    tree->data = 66;
    tree->left = new node;
    tree->right = new node;
    tree->left->left = new node;
    tree->left->left->left = new node;
    tree->left->left->right = new node;
    tree->left->left->left->left = new node;
    tree->left->left->left->right = new node;
    tree->left->left->left->right->right = new node;
    tree->right->right = new node;
    tree->right->left = new node;
    tree->right->left->left = new node;
    tree->right->left->right = new node;
    tree->right->left->right->left = new node;
    tree->left->data = 50;
    tree->left->left->data = 46;
    tree->left->left->left->data = 89;
    tree->left->left->right->data = 37;
    tree->left->left->left->left->data = 53;
    tree->left->left->left->right->data = 81;
    tree->left->left->left->right->right->data = 86;
    tree->right->data = 72;
    tree->right->left->data = 78;
    tree->right->right->data = 71;
    tree->right->left->left->data = 87;
    tree->right->left->right->data = 35;
    tree->right->left->right->left->data = 17;
}
void show_tree_view(struct node* const &tree, string view)
{
    queue<struct node*> box;
    box.push(tree);
    cout << box.front()->data << " ";
    int size = box.size();
    while(!box.empty())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            struct node* current = box.front();
            box.pop();
            if(current->left != nullptr) box.push(current->left);
            if(current->right != nullptr) box.push(current->right);
        }
        size = box.size();
        if(view == "left") cout << box.front()->data << " ";
        if(view == "right") cout << box.back()->data << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    struct node* tree = new node;
    construct(tree);
    /*int height = calculate_height_by_recursion(tree);
    cout << "height with recursion : " << height << endl;
    height = calculate_height_without_recursion(tree);
    cout << "height without recursion : " << height << endl;*/
    cout << "Left view of tree is : ";
    show_tree_view(tree, "left");
    //cout << "Right view of tree is : ";
    //show_tree_view(tree, "right");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above program, for all other functions(which I have removed due to large code) worked fine, but the function meant to show left and right view is not working. It neither shows any error. When I run the program, it shows segmentation fault :-
Output -

```
ujjaldas223@ujjal:~/Ujjal$ ./simple_tree
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I debug the above, but failed to catch the bug. Suggestion is required.

Comment: So you were not ready to debug this crazy code?  Also, there is no need to state `struct` everywhere you have `node`.  C++ is not `C`.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie That is because when I wrote code for calculating height(using level order traversal) it worked fine, and then copy-paste the same code shows core dump. It's really annoying you know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error is that your `show_tree_view` function fails to check to see if the `std::queue` is empty here:

```
 if (view == "left") cout << box.front()->data << " ";
 if (view == "right") cout << box.back()->data << " ";
```

Previous to this code, you called `box.pop()` in a loop, thus `box` is potentially empty.

I took your code and ran it using Visual Studio, and it stopped with an error pointing to the above set of lines.  Indeed, `size` is 0, and thus calling `box.front()` and `box.back()` will result in undefined behavior (in your case, a segmentation fault) occurring.

So you should check `box.empty()` first, and if it isn't empty, then it should be safe to call `box.front()` and `box.back()`.

Comment: Ok, let me check.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you very much. You have saved my lot of time.